# Best way to change FontAwsome stars class regular to solid

Tags: javascript, vue.js, font-awesome

I want to change the class of 5 stars of FontAwesome Icons from regular to solid according to a numeric variable `level`that changes from `0` to `5`

```html
<template>
    <div id="five-stars">
      <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-star" size="6x"/>
      <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-star" size="6x"/>
      <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-star" size="6x"/>
      <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-star" size="6x"/>
      <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-regular fa-star" size="6x"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ThreeScene",
  data() {
    return {
      level: 1
    };
  }
}
```

Can you please tell me how can I do that without repeating the `<div>` five times? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fa-${i <= level ? 'solid' : 'regular'}` help you :

```
<template>
  <div id="five-stars">
    <font-awesome-icon v-for="i in 5" :key="i" :icon="`fa-${i <= level ? 'solid' : 'regular'} fa-star`" size="6x"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ThreeScene",
  data() {
    return {
      level: 1
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [v-for loop](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-with-a-range)

```
<template>
    <div id="five-stars">
      <font-awesome-icon 
        v-for="level in 5" 
        :key="level"
        :icon="`${level} fa-star" 
        size="6x"
      />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const data = ref([
  'fa-solid',
  'fa-regular',
  'fa-solid',
  'fa-regular',
  'fa-solid'
])

</script>
```

note that the variable `level` will start with the value of `1`, not `0`.